# Find unanswered questions over last week or month

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

I am looking for a way to find unanswered questions over the last week or month for my favorite tags. Right now I monitor the [rss feed for my favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/rss-feed-of-your-favorite-tags)
but would like to extend it to see the questions that were left unanswered over last week/month. By unanswered I refer to questions that don't have any answers (not to be confused with questions that have answers that are not accepted yet or without any upvotes).

Even a programmatic way of achieving this would help!

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: Didn't follow why my question got a down vote. If the voter could explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [advanced search help tips](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) will be of use.

- favorite tags: `intags:mine`
- last month: `created:2014-11..2014-12`

  <sup>This will include the beginning of november to the end of december. Use `created:2014-12-01..2014-12-31` if you want it to be december only.</sup>

  last week: `created:2014-12-17..2014-12-24`
- no answers: `answers:0`
- questions: `is:question`

And easy clickable links:

<kbd>[For week](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intags%3Amine+created%3A2014-12-17..2014-12-24+answers%3A0+is%3Aquestion)</kbd>

<kbd>[For month](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intags%3Amine+created%3A2014-11..2014-12+answers%3A0+is%3Aquestion)</kbd>

Comment: Works well. After trying out for few parameters I realized that the list is unsorted, right? Any way to sort it by date?

Comment: @AndyDufresne By default the "relevance" tab is selected. Choose "newest" to sort by date.